Take just the integral and summation signs from the mtpro, with lualatex in a unicode setting
What could be a working strategy to get the integral symbols (\int, \oint, \iint, etc) and the summation symbol from the mathtime font, but otherwise use unicode fonts and unicode-math? There should be a way, but I couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?

You could do like the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LMP3}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP3}{mtt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}{<->mt2exa}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mtprolargesymbols}{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\sum}{\DOTSB\sum@\slimits@}%
  \renewcommand{\prod}{\DOTSB\prod@\slimits@}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"52}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"92}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"94}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"48}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"96}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"98}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\cwointop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"9A}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\awointop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"9C}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\cwintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"9E}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\barintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{170}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\slashintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{172}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\sum@}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"50}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\prod@}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"51}%
  \def\iint{\DOTSI\iintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\iiint{\DOTSI\iiintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\oiint{\DOTSI\oiintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\oiiint{\DOTSI\oiiintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\cwoint{\DOTSI\cwointop\ilimits@}%
  \def\awoint{\DOTSI\awointop\ilimits@}%
  \def\cwint{\DOTSI\cwintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\barint{\DOTSI\barintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\slashint{\DOTSI\slashintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\slsum{\DOTSB\slsumop\slimits@}%
  \def\slprod{\DOTSB\slprodop\slimits@}%
  \def\slcoprod{\DOTSB\slcoprodop\slimits@}%
  \def\upsum{\DOTSB\upsumop\slimits@}%
  \def\upprod{\DOTSB\upprodop\slimits@}%
  \def\upcoprod{\DOTSB\upcoprodop\slimits@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\int\oint\iint\sum\prod$

\[\int\oint\iint\sum\prod\]

\end{document}

In order to test, I actually used
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ifluatex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LMP3}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP3}{mtt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}{<->mt2exa}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mtprolargesymbols}{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\sum}{\DOTSB\sum@\slimits@}%
  \renewcommand{\prod}{\DOTSB\prod@\slimits@}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"52}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"92}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"94}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"48}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"96}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"98}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\cwointop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"9A}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\awointop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"9C}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\cwintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"9E}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\barintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{170}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\slashintop}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{172}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\sum@}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"50}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\prod@}{\mathop}{mtprolargesymbols}{"51}%
  \def\iint{\DOTSI\iintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\iiint{\DOTSI\iiintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\oiint{\DOTSI\oiintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\oiiint{\DOTSI\oiiintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\cwoint{\DOTSI\cwointop\ilimits@}%
  \def\awoint{\DOTSI\awointop\ilimits@}%
  \def\cwint{\DOTSI\cwintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\barint{\DOTSI\barintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\slashint{\DOTSI\slashintop\ilimits@}%
  \def\slsum{\DOTSB\slsumop\slimits@}%
  \def\slprod{\DOTSB\slprodop\slimits@}%
  \def\slcoprod{\DOTSB\slcoprodop\slimits@}%
  \def\upsum{\DOTSB\upsumop\slimits@}%
  \def\upprod{\DOTSB\upprodop\slimits@}%
  \def\upcoprod{\DOTSB\upcoprodop\slimits@}%
}
\makeatother
\else
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\fi

\begin{document}

$\int\oint\iint\sum\prod$

\[\int\oint\iint\sum\prod\]

\end{document}

so I could typeset the same with either pdflatex or lualatex and compare the output, which seems to be the same (a distinctive math font has been used for the check).
Caveat. Some other symbols might need treatment.

